# Unable to attach file in android

Tags: android, android-intent, email-attachments, android-image, android-implicit-intent

I want to attach file in a mail....The thing is I want to use `ACTION_SENDTO` .When I send the mail without an attachment it works fine but when I try to attach a file it gives an exception (`android.content.ActivityNotFoundException`) just like the following link:
[How to launch email intent with an attached image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060203/how-to-launch-email-intent-with-an-attached-image)

I tried what the answer in that said but didn't get it fixed.
Here's my code

```
Uri mail= Uri.fromParts("mailto",message, null);                                
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, mail);                
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, sub);
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, mailcontent);               
emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/ab.jpg"));
emailIntent.setType("image/jpg"); 
startActivity(emailIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use `Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);`
and `emailIntent .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);`

Comment: No.... I want to use only ACTION_SENDTO as i want to filter out 15+ applications that show up with ACTION_SEND....One could say use settype("message/rfc822") which filters out most of them but still some applications like skype still pop up

Answer (score 0):

Need to use the EXTRA_STREAM

```
        Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);

        Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile( file );
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, outputFileUri);
```

Comment: @user850688-I guess when i said "I want to use ACTION_SENDTO" it clearly meant that i don't need answers with ACTION_SEND

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
    private static final String MESSAGE_RFC822 = "message/rfc822";
    private static final String SELECT_EMAIL_APPLICATION = "Select email application.";

    public static void sendEmail(Context theContext, final String title, final String[] emails, final String theSubject, final String theBody,
        final File file) throws ActivityNotFoundException
{
    final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType(MESSAGE_RFC822);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, emails);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, theSubject);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, theBody);
    if (file != null) {
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://" + file.getAbsolutePath()));
    }

    theContext.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, SELECT_EMAIL_APPLICATION));
}
```

Comment: As i said I only want to use ACTION_SENDTO because even after specifying the mime type to "message/rfc822" applications such as skype responds to the Intent call which I don't want...